# link_to method post is not working Rails 2.3.9

Tags: ruby, link-to, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm trying to implement some link_to's using post method.

However, it always puts all the information as a query string in the browser's bar (it behaves as a GET).

Why?

Here is my code:

```
<%= link_to hotel[:name], {:controller => "gds_hotels", :action => "hotel_details",
                      :dest => @destination,
                      :ci => @check_in,
                      :co => @check_out,
                      :hotel => hotel,
                      :rooms => hotel[:rooms]}, :method => "POST" %>
```

Thank you! =)

Comment: Placing in comment as I have not tested this, but I believe `"POST"` should be a symbol like `:post`

Comment: I already tried that... and got same results...! =S

Comment: Do you have JavaScript disabled?  `link_to` when combined with a method relies on JavaScript to work.  It's safer to use `button_to` as Antoine recommends below.

Answer (score 2):

You should use button_to

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to